# How to get multiple input in the webservice

Tags: c#, web-services

Using C#

Currently I am using web service to display the employee details

Current Logic

```
Getting the 4 inputs (employee id, name, date of join, email) as a string, sending the input to DB as a parameter and retrieve the procedure output in dataset and displayed the dataset output (employee id, name, date of join, email, address, passport no, etc). This is working fine for single employee information.
```

Now I want to get the bulk employee input and display the bulk employees output in web service

How to get the bulk employees input details

For example, If the application want to get 20 employee details, then application need to provide employee id, name, date of join, email as a input for 20 employees.

How the application send a request to webservice for 20 * 4 = 80 input through dataset or any other idea?

Can any one help or suggest me

If the question is not clear or any doubt, please feel free to ask me.

Comment: Do you develop that web service?

Comment: What flavor of web service do you use?

Comment: Web service is already build, i need to change the logic, currently i am getting 4 input as a string, as per the new requirement i need to get 4 input for 20 times. How to acheive this

Answer (score 1):

Usually for something like that you need to do a POST with some kind of attached blob of data (the data itself can be any format you like, as long as your server will understand it and respond accordingly). You could conceivably pass them all in the URL but that'd be kinda crazy.

Comment: Completely agree. Get request has max length limitation

Answer (score 1):

You should create a class with the **request properties** like:

```
public class RequestParams
{
    public int employeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfJoin { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

this will be your Method input params:

```
public EmployeesDetails GetDetails(RequestParams[] r)
```

Make sure to use the same structure in your javascript and use JSON.Parse to have it parsed correctly

*Edit, example:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public EmployeesDetails GetDetails(RequestParams[] request)
    {


        // Query the database, request contains an array of  RequestParams
    }

public class RequestParams
{
    public int employeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfJoin { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
public class EmployeesDetails
{
    public int PassportNumber { get; set; }
}
```

JSON example (dont catch me on parsing error, i wrote it quickly manual):

```
{'request':[
'RequestParams':{
    'employeeID':'1',
    'Name':'1',
    'DateOfJoin':'1',
    'Email':'sgd@asdf.d'},
    {
    'employeeID':'2',
    'Name':'2',
    'DateOfJoin':'2',
    'Email':'sgd@asdf.d'},
    {
    'employeeID':'3',
    'Name':'3',
    'DateOfJoin':'3',
    'Email':'sgd@asdf.d'},
    {
    'employeeID':'4',
    'Name':'4',
    'DateOfJoin':'4',
    'Email':'sgd@asdf.d'}
}]}
```

Comment: User need to send a bulk input. As per the new logic user don't want to send 4 request 20 times, user need to send 4 * 20 input as a bulk request in one time

Comment: That's exacly what my code is doing..
take a look at the WebMethod, as it accepts an array of object

Comment: Tomerz, Can you please share some sample code with input and output , I am not fully understand your logic :(